# Command Headache - money system /w command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have set up a monetary system on my server using command blocks. I have set up a store to buy and sell item. However, you can only do 1 item at a time. I need to figure out how to sell a specified number or a stack of items at time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you're doing it. Let's say for the sake of example that a player has just paid 1 emerald and is now expecting 16 gravel in return.

If you're using `/give`, it's as simple as including the amount:

`/give PlayerNameHere minecraft:gravel 16`

If you're putting the items in a chest or having a villager trade them or something, you can change the number of items in a stack by using its NBT data:

`/...   {...{id:minecraft:gravel,Count:16b...}...}`

That's also how you'd test for the expected amount of currency. Sorry if this is unhelpful, I'd really need to see your commands to know how this would fit in.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would create a custom villager, using an excellent generator such as [this](https://minecraftcommand.science/shop-generator), then summoning it at the shop location in your world.

Link:https://minecraftcommand.science/shop-generator

Comment: It might be beneficial to include the highlights from that link in case thenlink no longer works.